# Using map() with two arguments where one argument is a list and the other an integer

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension, map-function, coding-efficiency

```
def change_salary(data: list, amt: int) -> list:
    new_data = data[:]
    new_data[1] += amt
    return new_data
    
def change_salaries(employees: list, amt: int) -> list:    
    return list(map(change_salary, employees, [amt]*amt))

employees = [
    ["Person1", 2000000],
    ["Person2", 2500000]
]

happier_employees = change_salaries(employees, 100000)
```

I have the following example code, and I want to add the same increase in salary to all employees in a list.  I am trying to work out whether I can use map() with one list and a variable containing an integer to produce the same output as using list comprehension in my *change_salaries* function:

```
return [change_salary(employee, amt) for employee in employees]
```

At the moment, in order for map to work, I have to fudge it by creating a list of amounts *amt*, so that it matches the list length of employees.  This can't be correct; it is certainly a very ugly solution.

I had hoped that I could do:

```
return list(map(change_salary, employees, amt))
```

Where *employees* is mapped to the employees argument and *amt* was mapped to the amt argument within change_salaries function.

Is what I am trying to do with map possible and, if so, what should the code be?

I have looked through the suggested posts before posting this question - I can't find a matching problem - perhaps because I am not using the correct terminology?

Comment: Thanks for the spot.  I have modified the example code in the `change_salary` function to prevent accidental side-effects.  The reason for the two functions is to be able to use one as a standalone function to change just one salary and another function to act as a change all salary function without having to write a loop.  It was just some code to showcase a point. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use currying, like with `partial` from `functools`:

```
from functools import partial

def change_salaries(employees: list, amt: int) -> list:
    return list(map(partial(change_salary, amt=amt), employees))
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  This is exactly what I needed - Partial Function Application!  Thanks!